# Alembic few modules to single database

Tags: sqlalchemy, alembic

We need to build a large application that split to multiple modules,

```
App
  - Module1    --> AppDb
  - Module2    --> AppDb
  - Module3    --> AppDb
```

Each module, we would like to add alembic version, all modules connect to single database. But we cannot add revision, because it's conflict to other module's revision (because all version store in same table **alembic_version**, so the migrations conflict with each other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using separate simple migrations in each of `Module1`, `Module2` and `Module3` each with their own `env.py` (or similar), the solution could be to use the `version_table` argument to [`context.configure`](https://github.com/zzzeek/alembic/blob/0e1c0989894f13b29a00c9504b887568a40d6648/alembic/templates/generic/env.py#L59), that allows you to override the name of the version table.

i.e. modify the `env.py` to something like

```
context.configure(
    connection=connection,
    target_metadata=target_metadata,
    version_table='alembic_module1_version'
)
```